# Convert Unsafe pointer to Span<T>

Tags: c#, memory, .net-core, task, helper

making convert from unsafe pointer to Span 
i tried to convert it but always gave me something wrong
so any help from Programmers

```
 public void Encrypt(Byte* pBuf, Int32 Length)
        {
            Kernel.assert(pBuf != null);
            Kernel.assert(Length > 0);

            Byte* pBlock = stackalloc Byte[CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE];
            Kernel.memcpy(pBlock, EncryptIV, CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE);

            while (Length-- > 0)
            {
                if (EncryptNum == 0)
                    Encipher(pBlock);

                Byte val = (Byte)(*pBuf ^ pBlock[EncryptNum ^ 3]);

                pBlock[EncryptNum ^ 3] = val;
                *(pBuf++) = val;

                EncryptNum = (EncryptNum + 1) & (CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE - 1);
            }
            Kernel.memcpy(EncryptIV, pBlock, CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
```

code i converted using Span

> this convertor gave me wrong Length every time length got changed

this is weird

```
 public unsafe void Encrypt(Span<byte> src, Span<byte> dst)
        {
            var Length = src.Length;
            byte* pBlock = stackalloc byte[CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE];
            NativeMethods.memcpy(pBlock, EncryptIV, CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE);
            int x = 0;
            while (Length-- > 0)
            {
                if (EncryptNum == 0)
                    Encipher(pBlock);

                var val = (byte)(src[x] ^ pBlock[EncryptNum ^ 3]);

                pBlock[EncryptNum ^ 3] = val;
                dst[x++] = val;
                EncryptNum = (EncryptNum + 1) & (CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE - 1);
            }

            NativeMethods.memcpy(EncryptIV, pBlock, CAST5_BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please add the detailed error message you got.. It gave you something wrong is not a helpful problem description

Comment: its gave me wrong Length